# Resolvers to stitched-schemas returns null

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, graphql, apollo-server

I had split my big schema file to separate schema files like bookSchema.js, userSchema.js, etc. like below:

```
/****** typedefs/userSchema.js ******/
const { gql } = require('apollo-server-express');
const UserSchema = gql`
extend type Query {
    whoami: User
}
type User {
    name: String!
}
`;

export default UserSchema;


/****** typedefs/index.js ******/
const { gql } = require('apollo-server-express');
import UserSchema from './userSchema';
import BookSchema from './bookSchema';

const DefaultSchema = gql`
    type Query {
        _: Boolean
    }
    type Mutation {
        _: Boolean
    }
`;

const Schema = [DefaultSchema, UserSchema, BookSchema];

export default Schema;
```

For each of the schema I define a corresponding resolver modules like below:

```js
/****** resolvers/bookResolver.js ******/
const Resolvers = {
    Query: {
        books: (_, args, {models}) => models.Book.findAll(),
    },
};

export default Resolvers;


/****** resolvers/index.js ******/
import UserResolvers from './userResolver';
import BookResolvers from './bookResolver';

const Resolvers = [UserResolvers, BookResolvers]

export default Resolvers;
```

Finally my app.js looks like below:

```js
import { ApolloServer, gql } from 'apollo-server-express';
import Schema from '../graphql/typedefs/';
import Resolvers from '../graphql/resolvers/';
import Models from '../models/';
import { mergeSchemas } from 'graphql-tools';

...

const schema = Schema;
const resolvers = Resolvers;
const models = Models;
const me = models.User.me();
const context = {
  models,
  me,
};

const mergedSchema = mergeSchemas({
  schemas: schema
});

const server = new ApolloServer({ schema: mergedSchema, resolvers, context });
```

And when I run the server and execute the graphql query in Graphiql web inerface, I get null values. Why aren't the resolvers mapping to the schema after I split the monolithic schema to smaller ones and use the merged one in my `ApolloServer` construction?

Would appreciate your thoughts on this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

For `"graphql-tools": "^6.0.15"`, the configuration `schemas` expects `GraphQLSchema[]` type. But the return value of `gql` function is `DocumentNode` type.

So I will use [makeExecutableSchema(options)](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/api/graphql-tools/#makeexecutableschemaoptions) function to get the schemas using corresponding typeDefs and resolvers for `User` and `Book` module.

But in fact, the role of `mergeSchemas` is not to organize code in a single graphql service. It is used to merge multiple graphql microservices into a graphql endpoint. See [schema-stitching](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/features/schema-stitching/)

> We can create references to all of the remote GraphQL APIs we want to use, and pass them into the mergeSchemas function to create a single API.

For organize code for a single graphql service, `makeExecutableSchema` function is good enough.

I will still give a solution to your problem.

E.g.

`resolvers/bookResolver.ts`:

```js
const Resolvers = {
  Query: {
    books: (_, args) => [{ name: 'jestjs' }, { name: 'js' }],
  },
};

export default Resolvers;
```

`resolvers/userResolver.ts`:

```js
const Resolvers = {
  Query: {
    whoami: (_, args, { models }) => ({ name: 'teresa teng' }),
  },
};

export default Resolvers;
```

`resolvers/index.ts`:

```js
import UserResolvers from './userResolver';
import BookResolvers from './bookResolver';

const Resolvers = [UserResolvers, BookResolvers];

export default Resolvers;
```

`typedefs/bookSchema.ts`:

```js
import { gql } from 'apollo-server-express';

const BookSchema = gql`
  type Query {
    books: [Book]!
  }
  type Book {
    name: String!
  }
`;

export default BookSchema;
```

`typedefs/userSchema.ts`:

```js
import { gql } from 'apollo-server-express';

const UserSchema = gql`
  type Query {
    whoami: User
  }
  type User {
    name: String!
  }
`;

export default UserSchema;
```

`typedefs/index.ts`:

```js
import userTypeDefs from './userSchema';
import bookTypeDefs from './bookSchema';
import { gql, makeExecutableSchema } from 'apollo-server-express';
import resolvers from '../resolvers';

const defaultTypeDefs = gql`
  type Query {
    _: Boolean
  }
  type Mutation {
    _: Boolean
  }
`;

const [UserResolvers, BookResolvers] = resolvers;
const userSchema = makeExecutableSchema({ typeDefs: userTypeDefs, resolvers: UserResolvers });
const bookSchema = makeExecutableSchema({ typeDefs: bookTypeDefs, resolvers: BookResolvers });
const defaultSchema = makeExecutableSchema({ typeDefs: defaultTypeDefs });

export default [userSchema, bookSchema, defaultSchema];
```

`app.ts`:

```js
import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server';
import schema from './typedefs';
import resolvers from './resolvers';
import { mergeSchemas } from 'graphql-tools';

const mergedSchema = mergeSchemas({
  schemas: schema,
});

const server = new ApolloServer({ schema: mergedSchema, resolvers });
const port = 3000;
server.listen(port).then(({ url }) => console.log(` Server ready at ${url}`));
```

Start the server, you will get the whole schema like this:

```
type Book {
  name: String!
}

type Mutation {
  _: Boolean
}

type Query {
  whoami: User
  books: [Book]!
  _: Boolean
}

type User {
  name: String!
}
```

source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/apollo-graphql-tutorial/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/63889126

Comment: Thanks for sharing your thoughts; it sure helped. I shared my answer on what changes got my code working with link to reference material that helped. Based on that, I think my approach is alright too. Thoughts??

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I managed to get things in order with slight modification to the `mergeSchemas(options)` method and `ApolloServer(config)` constructor like below:

```js
// Modification 1: Pass resolvers here
const mergedSchema = mergeSchemas({
  schemas: schema,
  resolvers : resolvers,
});

// Modification 2: DON'T pass resolvers here, for mergedSchema has it already!!..
const server = new ApolloServer({ 
  schema:mergedSchema, context 
});
```

Reference: https://hasura.io/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-schema-stitching-in-graphql-f30178ac0072/#a473